# How to know which column is created in existing table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have around 500 tables in my database and each table is having a minimum of 100 columns.We total 5 person are working in the same database.So whenever requirement arises then a new column or a table is added.What ever I make changes,I keep a record but my colleagues didnt do it.So I am facing problem now what others have created column in the existing table or a new table is created.

*So can anybody please tell me is it possible to know whether a new column is added to an existing table and if added what is the column name?*

Comment: the answer might be here: /questions/1231831/sql-server-diff-tool

Comment: You should re-think your development process. Nobody should be allowed to "just change" the tables. Each change should be put into a SQL script and stored in a version control system. Ideally identifying the version of your application to which it belongs. Look into Liquibase or Flyway for tools helping you to manage your schema migrations.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes you are right.I will do as per youcnow onwards But as everything has happened so how will I get added columns now?

Comment: Our application, Sql Historian (sqlhistorian.tessik.com), can do this work for you, and store all DB changes in Subversion or TFS.

Comment: Do you have a copy of both the old and new databases?  Or are you just trying to figure this out using the modified database?

Comment: @MarkMadej I have a copy of my original DB.we are not making any changes to original DB and neither do we have any access to it.After our project is completed then we will make changes in the original DB and for this purpose we have to know what new columns we have created in the DB

Comment: So you have a copy of the DB.  What do you mean you don't have access?  Do you not have a username/password that works for it?

Comment: @MarkMadej yes,we do not have username/password

Comment: Bummer, OK.  And this is on MS SQL Server, correct?  What version?

Comment: @MarkMadej yes its in ms sql server 2013

Answer (score 3):

May be this query help you

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS table_name,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
    c.name AS column_name,
    modify_date, create_date
FROM 
    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY 
    modify_date DESC
```

**EDIT**

To Audit this, You have to use DDL trigger

Step 1:- Create New Audit Table

```
CREATE TABLE DDLAudit 
(
  PostTime datetime, DatabaseName varchar(256), Event nvarchar(100), 
  ObjectName varchar(256), TSQL nvarchar(2000), Login varchar(256)
)
```

Step 2:- Create DDL Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER AuditChanges
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE
AS

DECLARE @ed XML
SET @ed = EVENTDATA()

INSERT INTO DDLAudit (PostTime, DatabaseName, Event, ObjectName, TSQL, Login) 
VALUES
(
    GetDate(),
    @ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
    @ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    @ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
    @ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)'),
    @ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
)
```

Now, Every Changes will be logged in Your `DDLAudit`. You can Filter out based on datetime filter on `PostTime` column.

Comment: Thanks piyush for answering,checked with your answer,It gives me columns which I have changed also some of columns which have never changed

Comment: This doesnt give the time of change

Comment: @SpringLearner:- you can use date filter to get modified value within  range

Comment: @Piyush how can I get columns names within 3 months from today?

Comment: @SpringLearner:- See Edit Section in Answer

Comment: @Piyush thanks again,You deserve +1.I think this will be triggered if I add a new column now.How can I know what all tables are created 3months back

Comment: @piyush, be aware the DDL trigger will only track changes after the trigger was created.  You cannot report changes made before today but can report changes made 3 months ago after April 2015.

Comment: @Piyush I need another help,would you mind helping me?

Comment: @SpringLearner:- if I could, I will. Let me know

Comment: @Piyush I was reading this answer and its really brilliant answer. I am also similar type problem. My problem is I am also having huge number of tables.we are 3 memebers handling a single DB. I want to know if some one is changing the tables(either insert,update or delete) then I want to capture the old value and new value.If its possible then I will post a question here.Waiting for reply

Answer (score 1):

Using the below query you can find the tables which were altered recently.

Query to know the table last altered

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
order by modify_date desc
```

Query to know the Column altered

```
SELECT TOP (select count(distinct(TransactionID))
from ::fn_trace_gettable( LEFT((select path from sys.traces where is_default = 1 ),len((select path from sys.traces where is_default = 1 )) - PATINDEX('%\%', reverse((select path from sys.traces where is_default = 1 )))) + '\log.trc', default )
where EventClass in (46,47,164) and EventSubclass = 0 and
DatabaseID <> 2  and
ObjectName='table1' and StartTime>'2015-01-10 00:00:00') [name],[colorder]
FROM [sys].[syscolumns]
where id=(SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables
where name='table1')
order by colorder desc
```

Note: this query will not work if there was any column dropped or the multiple columns of the table was altered using the SQL server UI but will keep track of multiple alter in the same query

The dropped column can be identified by the colorder. You will find the order will be missing but the column information you will not be able to see.

If you provide the table name and the date time, it gives the columns which were altered with order. 
If it doesnt return any value then it means there was no change made on the table.

Comment: thanks for the answer but how will I know which columns are modified

Comment: I m not sure whether SQL-Server really logs those details somewhere. Anyway i am digging the system tables about those information.

Comment: what is canara and colorder here?

Comment: Typo error. Thanks @piyush for editing. Colorder is the order of the columns created. last created column will have the highest colorder in that table.

Comment: I tried using your query. Actually I created 2 cols in a table but when I execute your query ,it gives only one column name

Comment: Have u provided the date time correctly? Hope your aim is only to know the column altered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68539/discussion-between-springlearner-and-manoj-gopi).

Comment: @SpringLearner Let me give a try.

Comment: I need another help please help me